# how to resolve error "Don't know how to build task 'build:iphone:setup_xcode_project'"

Tags: iphone, rhodes, rhomobile

I am getting the following error when I fire the command `build:iphone:setup_xcode_project` on my terminal:

> Don't know how to build task `build:iphone:setup_xcode_project`

I am using rhodes3.0.0 how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed xcode into your Mac correctly.

Please refer following link for better understanding how to build in Mac

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build#building-a-rhodes-application-for-iphoneipad